# T-SQL - table variable select

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I just wondering how to select values from table B according to table A col values; The idea is quite simple but I have confused a little

code like a

```
DECLARE @A TABLE
(
id INT NOT NULL,
name VARCHAR(50)

);

INSERT @A SELECT id,name FROM table1 WHERE id>10

DECLARE @B TABLE
(

  address VARCHAR(255),
  city VARCHAR(128)

);

INSERT @b SELECT address,city FROM table2
WHERE id=(SELECT id FROM @A)
```

Comment: Table B don't has id attribute. Please, post a sample  data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change "id =" to "id IN"

```
WHERE id=(SELECT id FROM @A)
```

to

```
WHERE id IN (SELECT id FROM @A)
```